# jQuery put values from array into text box but without commas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array `["A", "B", "C"]` and I want to show the elements of the array in a text box but without comma. They will appear in the text box as like: ABC

```js
function addtoFormula(){
    var a = ["A", "B", "C"];
    $.each([a], function( index, value ) {
        var putvalue = value;
        $("#formula").val(putvalue);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="formula" id="formula">
<button onclick="addtoFormula();">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to loop through the the array at all. Just use [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with empty string (`''`) as the separator:

```js
function addtoFormula(){
    var a = ["A", "B", "C"];
    $("#formula").val(a.join(''));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="formula" id="formula">
<button onclick="addtoFormula();">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply achieve this by

```
function addtoFormula() {
   var a = ["A", "B", "C"];
    $("#formula").val(a.join(''));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `join` method of the `array` to convert the array into a string

```
function addtoFormula(){
    var a = ["A", "B", "C"];
    // Note that join accept the join delimiter. Here I have 
    // space, but you can add what ever you need.
    $("#formula").val(a.join(''));     // Output: ABC
    $("#formula").val(a.join(' '));    // Output: A B C
    $("#formula").val(a.join(','));    // Output: A,B,C
    $("#formula").val(a.join(', '));    // Output: A, B, C
}
```